# Is there a master character arc list?

Tags: character-development

I am looking for a good website where they have a master list of character arcs from characters in movies. Can't seem to find one.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for...but [the 36 Dramatic Situations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thirty-Six_Dramatic_Situations) seems [somewhat relevant](https://gideonsway.wordpress.com/2009/10/31/screenwriting-tip-15-the-36-dramatic-situations/)..

Comment: have you browsed the great and terrible TVtropes.org?

Comment: Probably the best or closest thing you will find is going through IMDB or Wikipedia and looking up individual movies as you see fit.  This isn't a terrible idea but it would also be extremely tedious to keep track of and write out.  So I doubt you will find a dedicated site, but I would do research on specific movies that come to mind.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer to this question, but you can give [www.helpingwritersbecomeauthors.com/story-structures/](http://www.helpingwritersbecomeauthors.com/story-structures/) a try. It's not quite a character arc list, but it is a good place to start if you're still looking.